# sub routine with parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to optionally pass a parameter to my Excel vba script, but as soon as I add parameters, I can't run the code anymore. The idea behind it is that I have 2 radio buttons and a regular button in my spreadsheet and based on the selection, the script acts slightly different.

So it currently looks like this

```
Sub Assessment_Tool()
```

but I'd like to have it like this

```
Sub Assessment_Tool(Optional culture as String = "Int")
```

Without the parameter I can run my script (Assessment_Tool is showing up)
[image: w/o parameter]

When I add one, my script is not in the list anymore (Assessment_Tool missing)
[image: w/ parameter]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or is this not supposed to work like that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not the most elegant way, but, have you tried to create a simple sub with no parameters that calls your sub `Assessment_Tool` with parameters?

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns sorry I just added more context to my original post "The idea behind it is that I have 2 radio buttons and a regular button in my spreadsheet and based on the selection, the script acts slightly different." I need to rely on the user to make a selection what kind of assessment he is working with. Based on that selection, the script does some pieces differently. So I kinda need this initial parameter

Comment: Then again, as @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns stated, make a second sub calling the one with parameters with an If statement depending on the cell value it will call it with or without parameters.

Comment: @Damian hmm, sorry I don't see how that would help me. If I have another sub that calls my Assessment_Tool, this second sub would also rely on the parameter the user selects in the first place.

sub Another_Sub(culture as String)
call Assessment_Tool(culture)
end sub

or am I misunderstanding your suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want your subroutine in the macro list? You put the subroutine behind a click of a button...?

Comment: I was answering to the part *my script is not in the list anymore*. Now that you updated question, why just not assign the macro to the click of your button, as @EvR suggests?

Comment: Hi @EvR I also can't assign the script to a button as soon as I'd like to have a parameter being passed - it is just not there to assign. I think I have to come up with a work-around with a userform. But thats something I can only do on a Windows machine, because Mac Excel 365 does not support userforms Oo

Comment: @Claus Maier, yes you can, just rename your assigned sub

Comment: @EvR ok, let me test it, I'll come back later - thanks a lot for your help all